# permanently remove airplane mode from Ubuntu 20.04LTS

Tags: wireless-networking

How can I completely remove airplane mode from my system? Not talking about disabling it, but removing the option completely...

Every time I disable my wifi before going into standby or hibernating (required to keep the internal PCI wifi from dying upon waking... another ubuntu 20.04LTS issue with the iwl3945 driver not fixed yet), it goes into airplane mode which I then MUST ALSO disable before going into standby/hibernate or risk losing my PCI wifi upon waking. In my case, it is merely a nuisance and needs to be deleted/removed/expunged!

Any ideas/tips/solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Quite hacky but working solution to restore wifi connection. Wery usefull when  computer is headless and you are connecting remotely.

```
crontab -e
```

inside write:

```
* * * * * /usr/sbin/rfkill unblock all
```

I tries to unblock wifi and bluetooth every minute.

And maybe you need to add user to the `rfkill` group (Ubuntu 20.04 work well without that).